# Problem with a WLOG in a commutativity theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the proof of second theorem in the [pdf](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-03/S0002-9939-1950-0036226-7/S0002-9939-1950-0036226-7.pdf), the author begins by affirming that it can be assumed WLOG  "that every element has characteristic some power of a fixed prime $p$". So, my questions would be:

1. What could the author mean by "characteristic of an **element**"? Maybe, for an element $a \in A$, the minimum $n$ such that $\sum_{1}^{n}a = 0$? Or perhaps, the characteristic of the subring generated by $a \in A$?
2. Then, why can he assume "that every element has characteristic some power of a fixed prime $p$" without loss of generality?

I understand that it may be a silly question, probably with an easy answer, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The phrasing does seem a bit strange, since that's a well-known fact for every finite division ring. So it's not really an assumption, and there's no more general case to be concerned about losing.

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, i don't seem to understand what you mean. Because, aren't there infinite rings such that every proper subring is finite? Some weeks ago, i found a paper about the characterization of such rings.